# magento filter collection using finset

Tags: magento

I am trying to use find_in_set on magento collection but have problem using it,
how to use finset to filter records from multiple ids

```
//i.e $cat_ids = array(16,17); this doesnt work
//i.e $cat_ids = array(16);  this works
```

below is the collection on which i am doing the filter

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

                $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left outer')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array(
                     array('finset' => $cat_ids),
                ));
```

Comment: Haven't used it for a long time, but doesn't `finset` use a comma separated string as value?

Answer (score 4):

have you tried using in instead of finset?

Comment: $collection->getSelect()->distinct(true); that should remove duplicates